# Loop over several dataframes to do several actions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have several dataframes (`dataframe_1`, `dataframe_2`...) that I want to loop in order to execute the same functions over all the dataframes. These functions are:

- Select specific columns:

```
dataframe_1 <- dataframe_1[, c("Column_1", "Column_2")]
```

- Rename the columns:

```
dataframe_1 <- rename(dtaframe_1, New_Name_for_Column_1 = Column_1)
```

- Create new columns. For example, by using the `ifelse()` function:

```
dataframe_1$Column_3 <- ifelse(dataframe_1$Column_1 = 5, 1, 0)
```

I have proven the code with some dataframes individually without errors.

However, if I execute the following loop:

```
list_dataframes = list(dataframe_1, dataframe_2)

for (dataframe in 1:length(list_dataframes)){
 dataframe <- dataframe[, c("Column_1", "Column_2")]
 dataframe <- rename(dtaframe, New_Name_for_Column_1 = Column_1)
 dataframe$Column_3 <- ifelse(dataframe$Column_1 = 5, 1, 0)
}
```

The following error arises:

```
Error in dataframe[, c("Column_1", "Column_2",  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

(All dataframes have the same column names.)

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: in the for loop, dataframe is an integer number and not a data.frame element. Eg for dataframe in 1:length(...) means dataframe will be 1,2,3...etc. your code is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not iterating over the list of dataframes, but rather over a sequence `1:length(list_dataframes)`. Consider the following for illustration:

```
a = list("a", "b")
for (i in a){print(i)}
for (i in 1:length(a)){print(i)}
```

In your code, you need to explicitly access the list elements like this:

```
list_dataframes = list(dataframe_1, dataframe_2)

for (df_number in 1:length(list_dataframes)){
  list_dataframes[[df_number]] <- list_dataframes[[df_number]][, c("Column_1", "Column_2")]
  list_dataframes[[df_number]] <- rename(list_dataframes[[df_number]], New_Name_for_Column_1 = Column_1)
  list_dataframes[[df_number]]$Column_3 <- ifelse(list_dataframes[[df_number]]$Column_1 = 5, 1, 0)
}
```

Comment: By doing that, the error does not appear anymore. However, I do not get any results: my dataframes number of columns remains the same.

Comment: Have a look at the edited second part of my answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: Your solution is corrected, @Scriddie. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

the code `for (dataframe in 1:length(list_dataframes))` creates a vector of numbers `c(1,2)` in which the value of one value at a time is stored in a variable named `dataframe`. This iteration variable is scalar i.e. it has 1 dimension and a length of 1. This is why you can not subset doing `dataframe[, c("Column_1", "Column_2")]` Do this instead: `list_dataframes[[dataframe]][, c("Column_1", "Column_2")]`

Comment: If I do that, this error arises: `Error in UseMethod("rename") : 
  no applicable method for 'rename' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"`

Comment: This is the same issue: `dataframe` is the iterator index variable and not the dataframe itself. You do not need the index but the actual data frame, so you probably want to use `purrr::map` or `lapply` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to iterate over dataframes using `purrr::map_dfr()`, e.g.

```
list_dataframes = list(dataframe_1, dataframe_2)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list_dataframes %>% 
  map_dfr(~.x %>% 
            select(Column_1, Column_2) %>% 
            rename(New_Name_for_Column_1 = Column_1) %>% 
            mutate(Column3= ifelse(Column_1 == 5, 1, 0)))
```